# ImportError: No module named 'knn'

Tags: pytorch, knn

I am trying to install PU_GAN repository and after installing knn_cuda module and trying to call it on python shell I get this error:

```
import knn_cuda
        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "", line 1, in
        File "C:\Users\49152\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\knn_cuda_init_.py", line 38, in
        knn = load_cpp_ext("knn")
        File "C:\Users\49152\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\knn_cuda_init.py", line 26, in load_cpp_ext
        ext = load(
        File "C:\Users\49152\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1079, in load
        return _jit_compile(
        File "C:\Users\49152\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1317, in _jit_compile
        return _import_module_from_library(name, build_directory, is_python_module)
        File "C:\Users\49152\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\cpp_extension.py", line 1699, in _import_module_from_library
        file, path, description = imp.find_module(module_name, [path])
        File "C:\Users\49152\anaconda3\envs\torch\lib\imp.py", line 296, in find_module
        raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
        ImportError: No module named 'knn'
```

I am using :

```
pytorch                   1.8.1           py3.8_cuda10.1_cudnn7_0    pytorch
knn-cuda                  0.2                      pypi_0    pypi
cudatoolkit               10.1.243             h74a9793_0
python                    3.8.8                hdbf39b2_5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should import it like this:

```
from knn_cuda import KNN
```

Then use it like,

```
knn = KNN(k=7)
```

Comment: I tried that and it is always not working

Comment: Try to install it from here : https://github.com/unlimblue/KNN_CUDA